# Bash function: into a 2D array, remove line and column identified by one index

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to create a bash function (basically, put into my bashrc).

The goal is to remove a line and a column indexed by a number (an integer), this number being the second argument of bash function (`$2`) and the first argument being the filename (`$1`).

I tried this but I can't get to make it work (I am under MacOS Mojave) :

```
function remove_line_column() { gsed '"$2"d' $1 | awk -v ind_field=$2 '!(ind_field="")' ;}
```

I am doing confusions between `expanding Shell arguments` (like `"$2"`) and `Shell arguments` (like only `$2`).

In direct command line, I can get the wanted result (removing 8th line and 8th column) by doing :

```
awk 'NR == 8 {next} {print}' file.txt | awk '!($8="")'
```

How to implement it as a Bash function ?

I would like to call it from the terminal like this :

```
$remove_line_column file.txt 8`
```

Comment: FYI, `function foo() {` is mixing legacy ksh syntax (`fuction foo {`) and POSIX sh syntax (`foo() {`) in a way that's incompatible with *both* legacy ksh and baseline POSIX sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remove_line_column() {
  awk -v remove="$2" 'NR == remove {next} {$remove = ""; print}' <"$1"
}
```

...used as in:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '1 2 3' '4 5 6' '7 8 9'
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
$ printf '%s\n' '1 2 3' '4 5 6' '7 8 9' | remove_line_column /dev/stdin 2
1  3
7  9
$ printf '%s\n' '1 2 3' '4 5 6' '7 8 9' | remove_line_column /dev/stdin 3
1 2
4 5
```

Comment: Great and simple ! Regards

Comment: Hello, just as reminder, the `print`after the `{$remove = "";}`  prints all field by default except the field with `$remove = $2`  : I don't understand exactly the order of executions in this command line : if you could explain me a little bit more about it ... Regards

Comment: @youpilat13, awk scripts consist of condition/action pairs. The default condition is "always true"/"run this every line". The default action is "print the whole line". So, where `NR==remove` is the condition, the action is to skip further processing for that line. And for *all* lines, excepting those we skipped that way, we clear the remove column and print what's left.